# Probability of winning the lottery: how are those two interpretations different?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, lotteries

Winning this specific lottery consists of choosing 5 numbers from a list of 50 numbers $\{1,2,3,...,50\}$ and then choosing 2 numbers from a list of 9 $\{1,2,...,9\}$. You win if all your numbers are chosen by the host on tv.

The correct approach is to say that there are a total of ${50\choose 5}\cdot{9\choose2}$ possibilities of choosing the numbers and just one winning combination $\implies$ the probability of winning is $\frac{1}{{50\choose 5}\cdot{9\choose2}}=\frac{1}{76275360}$

But here's a different approach: it doesn't matter if the nubers chosen on tv are chosen before or after you choose your combination, so let's assume the winning numbers are already chosen: $\{x_1,...,x_5,y_1,y_5\}\ \mid\ x_i\in[50], \ y_j\in[9]$

The probability of choosing one right number from the [50] list as your first number is $\frac{5}{50}$, the probability that the second number you choose is right is $\frac{4}{49}$ etc and we get $$\Bbb P[\text{winner}]=\frac{5!}{50\cdot49\cdot48\cdot47\cdot46}\cdot\frac{2\cdot1}{9\cdot8}$$ which is a different probability.

EDIT:

They are actually the same probability [image: wolfram alpha]

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Suppose I choose $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ from the fifty and then I choose $\{1,2\}$ from the nine.  Do I then need to match just on $1-5$, so just five matches?  Or ought I to interpret the nine as separate...so, really, $\{A,B,\cdots,I\}$, so I still need seven matches?

Comment: your second formula, where you just say "etc" without giving details on how you got it, is incorrect..  It should be $\frac{5!}{40\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46}\cdot \frac{1}{9\cdot 8}$ which is exactly the same as the first result.

Comment: @user247327 could you explain how you get your formula? and do you mean 50 instead of 40 in the denominator?

Comment: Your “correct approach” should read ${50\choose 5}\cdot{9\choose2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the "40" to "50".

Comment: If you're now satisfied that you know the answer to your original question you can answer it yourself, or delete it. Please do one of the other so the question doesn't remain on the unanswered queue.